# How to find through JSON array which has nested object elements

Tags: javascript, json

Below is my JSON array and I want to find if  `contact` array has specific value or not.

```
 data =  [ { _id: 5a67294923aba20014e2fe5a,
            customerLocation: '473 Victoria St, Singapore 198371',
            customerName: 'UNIVERSAL',
            id: 'UNI3L2',
            customerType: 'customer',
            contact:
             [ 'Brian spilak',
               'Brian spilak2',
               'Brian spilak3',
               'Brian spilak4',
               'Brian spilak5' ] } ];
```

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
function findContact(data,con){
           return data.contact.find(item => {
            return item.data.contact == con;
        })
     }    

    console.log('Contact Name :', findContact(data,'Brian spilak2'));
```

Comment: @joe-tom help than ;)

Comment: replace item.data.contact == con; with just item == con;

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to find. Will data have more than one customer object? Are you trying to find a particular customer? Or will it always just have one object?

Comment: @Mark_M No there will be only one customer object and one contact object. I want to find if contact object has specific value or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `indexOf`.Since it is only one object `data[0]` is used to get the first object, if it is an array of object you can use forEach method

```js
var data = [{
  _id: '5a67294923aba20014e2fe5a',
  customerLocation: '473 Victoria St, Singapore 198371',
  customerName: 'UNIVERSAL',
  id: 'UNI3L2',
  customerType: 'customer',
  contact: ['Brian spilak',
    'Brian spilak2',
    'Brian spilak3',
    'Brian spilak4',
    'Brian spilak5'
  ]
}];

function findContact(data, con) {
  if (data[0].contact.indexOf(con) !== -1) {
    return 'found';
  } else {
    return 'not found';
  }

}

console.log('Contact Name :', findContact(data, 'Brian spilak2'));
```

Answer (score 2):

`item` doesn't have `data.contact` property and your `data` response it an array, so you have to specify an index do work with:

```
function findContact(data,con){
           return data[0].contact.find(item => {
            return item == con;
        })
     }
```

Comment: `data` is an array. It has no `contact` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `data.contact` for contact data shown

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#find` with `array#includes` to check if a name exists in the `contact` property of the object.

```js
var data = [ { _id: '5a67294923aba20014e2fe5a', customerLocation: '473 Victoria St, Singapore 198371', customerName: 'UNIVERSAL', id: 'UNI3L2', customerType: 'customer', contact: [ 'Brian spilak', 'Brian spilak2', 'Brian spilak3', 'Brian spilak4', 'Brian spilak5'] } ];
var result = data.find(o => o.contact.includes('Brian spilak2'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why are you using `some()` rather than just the returned boolean from `includes()`?

Comment: Some is used here to iterate the array.

Comment: @HassanImam What if i want to return found object ?

Comment: I have updated the solution to return the complete object.

Answer (score 0):

This one returns all the objects matching the name criteria in the array.

```
function filterName(data, srchName) {
   return data.filter((obj) => {
        return obj.contact.indexOf(srchName) !== -1
    })
}

console.log(filterName(data, 'Brian spilak'));
```